# function that adds 16-bit variables

Tags: c, emulation, addition, x86-16, 16-bit

I am writing my first emulator (Intel 8086 microprocessor).

I'm stuck because I have to write a function that adds 16-bit variables together. Here is the prototype of the function I want to write:

`uint16_t add(uint16_t reg, uint16_t operand);`

For example, if we execute :

`add(5, 3)`

The function should do the calculation like this:

```
              111
  0000000000000101 (= 5)
+ 0000000000000011 (= 3)
  ----------------
              1000 (= 8)
```

and return 8.

To write this function, I need to find a way to access each bit of the two variables, then to be able to add them together and place them in a third variable.

Is this possible in C and if so can someone enlighten me on this?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Hm. `reg + operand` is doing exactly this...

Comment: Yes, but it won't behave exactly the way I want to. For example, in the event of a overflow, the operator + will segfault. But with my add function, I'm just going to set the CF flag.

Comment: No, operator `+` never segfault. You can easily check for "overflow" (which is actually a well-defined "wrap-around" for unsigned integers) and set your CF. If you make your temporary result variable `uint32_t`, then you can easily check if it exceeds the range of `uint16_t`.

Comment: So it's normal addition but with carry. What is the CF in this context, some global variable?

Comment: I have a global variable `uint16_t registers[]`. `registers[10] = FLAGS`. the bit 0 of the FLAGS uint16_t variable is the carry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming 32 bit computer, this is very trivial:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

_Bool carry;

uint16_t add (uint16_t reg, uint16_t operand)
{
  carry = (reg + operand) & 0xFFFF0000u;
  return reg + operand;
}

int main (void)
{
  int sum = add(65535, 1);
  printf("%d, CF:%d\n", sum, (int)carry);
}
```

Where `reg + operand` will get promoted to 32 bit `int` and in case the addition goes beyond 16 bits, the boolean flag will get set to 1.

Comment: Yes but as I write an emulator it doesn't matter. It is simply necessary that the result is in 16 bits.

Comment: Ah, ok. I was under the impression it needs to run on 8086

Comment: @EugeneSh. It would then use a software lib for 32 bit types, as 8 and 16 bit microcontrollers do. And for this reason the generated machine code gets very bloated if you use 32 bit numbers with no hardware support for them.

Comment: @Lundin What I meant that the line `carry = (reg + operand) & 0xFFFF0000u` wont work for 16-bit ints. But apparently it is most likely won't be an issue as it is going to run on a modern PC.

Answer (score 1):

You very roughly need something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int carry = 0;

uint16_t add(uint16_t reg, uint16_t operand)
{
  uint32_t result = (unint32_t)reg + operand;

  carry = 0;
  if (result > 0xffff)
    carry = 1;

  return result &= 0xffff;
}


int main()
{
  uint16_t r1, r2, r3;

  r1 = 0x10;
  r2 = 0x1000;
  r3 = add(r1, r2);
  printf("r3 = %04x, carry = %d\n", r3, carry);

  r1 = 0x11;
  r2 = 0xffff;
  r3 = add(r1, r2);
  printf("r3 = %04x, carry = %d\n", r3, carry);
}
```

Adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who took the time to answer my question! Indeed, I hadn't thought of doing it like that, it's a very good idea.Well this will only run on machines that can store 32-bit variables (but after all, there aren't many that don't).

 Thank You

Comment: @NathanCasabieille Standard C requires a 32 bit type to be present on the target system, since it must support `long` type.

Comment: In this case there is no problem, thank you for this information !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the nth bit (the 0th bit is the least significant bit, the 16th bit is the most significant bit), you can do

```
uint8_t bit = (num >> n) & 1;
```

What this does is it right shifts the number `n` bits, so the bit you want is the least significant bit, then it does a bitmask to only get that bit.

Comment: This is answering the "Y" part of the XY-problem.